# How to clear a pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to set the pictureBox1 Image to null but it didn't clear it before adding the next image.  so each time it's adding another image it's adding it on the one before.

then I tried to add a Dispose for the pictureBox1 Image but then it throw exception on the line:

```
pictureBox1.Image = milimeters[macTrackBar4.Value - 1];
```

without the Disposing line it's not throwing the exception but also not clearing the pictureBox1 before adding the next image.

```
private void macTrackBar4_ValueChanged(object sender, decimal value)
{
    if (milimeters != null && macTrackBar4.Value > 0 && macTrackBar4.Value <= milimeters.Length)
    {
        // Dispose of the current image if it exists
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        }

        // Clear the PictureBox
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate(); // Invalidate to clear the PictureBox

        // Assign the new image
        pictureBox1.Image = milimeters[macTrackBar4.Value - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not clearing it if you are immediately setting a new image?

Comment: You just need: `pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = [The New Image];`. Now, since you have previously posted a question related to this, and you have a procedure that synchronously - in the same event handler, IIRC -- takes a screenshot of the parent Form, you need to also synchronously refresh the PictureBox. So, call `Refresh()` instead of `Invalidate()` (the former is `Invalidate()` + `Update()` <- which means *do it now*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning a new image to a `pictureBox` it automatically removes the previous image and replaces it with the new image. There is no need to dispose of the old image unless you want the `pictureBox` to be blank for an amount of time before switching to the new one. The code below will replace the image of a `pictureBox` with a new one.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Resources.MyPicture;
```

Replace `MyPicture` with your imported image or resource.

Comment: Disposing of the previous Image is absolutely needed, unless it comes from a collection that is currently in use, since you don't want to dispose of objects that are needed later. The objects in this collection must be disposed when the collection itself is not required anymore -- If the Images come from Resources, then you need to dispose of the previous one

Comment: So when you change the pictureBox1.Image it layers the images over each other? Thats fascinating. I never knew that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Nope. It installs (that's [the term used in the Framework](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Controls/PictureBox/PictureBox.cs,293)) a new object; the previous object is not disposed (of course, it belongs to the dev :). That's why you need to explicitly dispose of the previous image. If, as mentioned, it's not used for other reasons, so it's stored. The Resource Manager, on the other hand, creates a new object each time you ask for one, even if it's the same object. In other words, it's a Factory

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry it's kind of hard for me to understand. I'm a minor and I've only been working with C# WinForms for a couple of years. Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind that graphic objects hold unmanaged resources (GDI+ handles), so you need to dispose of those objects when not needed anymore. The GC can't help you